# Detecting which version of IE is installed on your OS in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, windows-services, httpwebrequest

I am currenting manintaining a windows service that programmatcially generates a HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse objects for retrieving the response message of the request.

The `UserAgent` property of the HttpWebRequest was hard coded to use IE 6 as the browser agent.  Is the a way to programmatcially detect which version of IE is installed on the server hosting the service?

It is currently hosted on a Windows Server 2003 machine and might be installed on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect IE version from a WinForms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294809/detect-ie-version-from-a-winforms-application)

Comment: @RowlandShaw actually that question is specific to WinForms. It is more like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553984/how-do-i-detect-which-version-of-internet-explorer-is-installed. However, this question is older than both of those, so technically speaking, they are the duplicates :)

Answer (score 2):

you can also extract it from the WebBrowser control itself, if you have created one:

```
WebBrowser  browser = new WebBrowser();
Version ver = browser.Version;
```

Warning: this must be called from STA thread, otherwise it throws an exception.
This can be encountered in MSTest cleanup code, which is MTA, not STA.

Comment: Seems like overkill to add a reference to WinForms just for this. See linked answers for better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user agent can be set: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx

I prefer the WebClient class these days, it's a wrapper for HttpWebRequest and allows you to do some things with less code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx