# How do I detect which version of Internet Explorer is installed?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser

Is the best way to look under the Uninstall key of the Windows Registry?
Is there a Microsoft API call which provides this info and is it supported from XP onwards?

What is the best way to detect which version of Internet Explorer is installed on the local machine?

Answer (score 21):

You have to look in the registry, but not in uninstall key. Instead, 
find the key at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer` and read the value named `Version`.

For newer versions (IE 10 and above), `Version` is 9.x (for example, IE 10 is 9.10.something), and the new `svcVersion` value gives the true IE version.

This technique is even recommended by Microsoft; see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393).

Comment: Surprisingly enough, there's no API for this, and checking this registry key is generally accepted as the best choice.

Comment: Link is (probably) broken

Answer (score 4):

If you require to know the IE version into a web application you can get the User-Agent or use javascript:

You got here a Microsoft sample of how to get the internet Explorer version
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(VS.85).aspx

If you require to detect the IE Version into a Desktop program with X language you need to read the Windows registry

This registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer` contains the attribute `Version` with the IE version

Answer (score 4):

The Version value doesn't seem to include the Internet Explorer version information that you would most likely need.  Instead, look at either svcVersion or svcUpdateVersion for the information.

As an example, I am running IE 10 and if I query the Version registry value 9.10.9200.16798 is returned but if I query svcUpdateVersion 10.0.13 is returned.  The latter corresponds to the actual Internet Explorer version which is 10.

REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"  /v Version
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    Version    REG_SZ    **9.10.9200.16798**

REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"  /v svcUpdateVersion
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    svcUpdateVersion    REG_SZ    **10.0.13**

REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    svcVersion    REG_SZ    **10.0.9200.16798**

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to challenge the conventional wisdom of inspecting the registry. Consider the reference source for [System.Windows.Forms.WebView.Version](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WebBrowser.cs,3013ded900e5031e):

```cs
string mshtmlPath = 
   Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "mshtml.dll");
FileVersionInfofvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(mshtmlPath);
return new Version(
             fvi.FileMajorPart, fvi.FileMinorPart, fvi.FileBuildPart, fvi.FilePrivatePart);
```

Presumably, the guys who wrote the `WebView` class knew what they were doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also know the IE version on multiple computers using this script:

```
@Echo off

Cls

MD C:\SYSADMIT > NUL 

Echo. > c:\SYSADMIT\Resultados.txt

SET ListaEquipos=C:\SYSADMIT\ListaEquipos.txt

For /F "Tokens=*" %%z In (%ListaEquipos%) Do (

echo %%z  >> c:\SYSADMIT\Resultados.txt 

reg query "\\%%z\hklm\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion >> c:\SYSADMIT\Resultados.txt

)
```

Inside the file: `ListaEquipos.txt`, there is a list of computers.

It is also necessary to check `RemoteRegistry` service enabled on the target computers.

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/08/windows-buscar-version-de-internet-explorer-en-equipo-remoto.html