# Query Internet Explorer version from command line does not always work?

Tags: scripting, command-line, cmd

Step 1, I use the following command to get my local IE version from command line window:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v  version"
```

It will work and give me the IE version like this:

```
  ! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    version     REG_SZ  7.0.5730.13
```

Step 2, Now I try to use this command:

```
 reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v  version"  | find "version"
```

It would fail and tell me the following:

```
! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer

Error:  The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value
```

Step 3, Now if I go back to the first command:

```
 reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v  version"
```

it will give me the same error as in step 2.
What I dont understand is why step 2 would fail, and why step 3 will fail since it's the same as step 1.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553984/how-do-i-detect-which-version-of-internet-explorer-is-installed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In step 2 you are looking for registry value named `version"  | find "version`. Remove the double quote after version and everything will be OK:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v version | find "version"
```

Comment: Omit `find "version"`, and the resulting command will be compatible with Git Bash, MSYS, Cygwin, etc.

Comment: @mcandre For information I had to use `//v` instead of `/v` in Git Bash to make it work

Answer (score 5):

I found this command to be more accurate in its reporting of the version number
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v  "svcVersion"

Comment: How is this better and how would you type it in cmd prompt?

Comment: The same as the above, add reg query in front of it. The key by MBu is telling me that I've got version 9 installed, but it's really version 11. Ycl his reg key is giving me the correct version.

Comment: `svcVersion` is not there in Windows XP. It seems that one needs to query `svcVersion` (will be there for IE>=9), if it's not there, then `version`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553984/how-do-i-detect-which-version-of-internet-explorer-is-installed and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393